# How to define a bean in ApplicationContext.xml that has no constructor?

Tags: java, xml, javabeans, applicationcontext

I have a class

```
public class DataStore {
    public String name;
    public String username;
    public String password;
    public String token;
    public String connectionString;
    public String type;
    public String scheme;

    public boolean usesBasicAuth;
    public boolean usesBearerAuth;
}
```

I need to create an bean for it in another project. But i need to fill the fields somehow. The problem is I can not use `<constructor-arg ... />` because there is no constructor.

The code below results in BeanCreationException: "Could not resolve matching constructor"

```
 <bean id="dataStore"
      class="com.fressnapf.sdk.dataaccess.services.DataStore">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="${spring.datastore.name}"/>
    ...
</bean>
```

Comment: Solution: Use `property`, where `constructor-arg` is used (https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.m3/reference/html/creating-bean-definitions.html)

Comment: You can use <bean id="dataStore" class="com.fressnapf.sdk.dataaccess.services.DataStore"> to create a bean. **Note:** ->Every class in java has  a default constructor automatically provided by compiler

Comment: @ShubhamGarg yes, but i need to fill it with values, thats the thing, i dont need an emty bean

Comment: All the fields are **public** in this bean so you can set values after creation of the bean

Comment: @ShubhamGarg I need to read them from application.properties like this: ${spring.datastore.name}

Comment: @SGTechEdge  you can use <property name="name" value="${spring.datastore.name}"/>

Comment: @xerx593 it worked, make a answer out of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, You have public (getters and setters for your) properties, and only the "default (no args) constructor", then You can change your configuration to:

```xml
<bean id="dataStore" class="com.fressnapf.sdk.dataaccess.services.DataStore">
  <property name="connectionString" value="..."/>
  <!-- ... -->
</bean>
```

Using `property` instead of `constructor-arg`.

Docs (Spring 4.2): https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a constructor.

If you don't explicitly put one, Java will automatically add a default (non argument) constructor.

Use that one.
It will set all the instance variables to the default value of their type.

In your case: null for every String variable, false for every boolean.

Comment: But i need to set the Fields inside datastore

Comment: So, either add a constructor, or use setters

Comment: I did with setters and used property. now its working